# Nothing prints in text file

Tags: powershell, output

One thing you learn about programming is always dealing with errors. 
In this situation, my program doesn't have errors, however; nothing seems to print.
I simply want my group name and managedby information in 2 columns. Can you explain why nothing outputs?

```psh
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

$exportlist = "C:\Temp\managedby.txt"

Clear-Content $exportlist

$Header = `
"Group ID Name" + "|" + "ManagedBy"

$Header | Out-File $exportlist -Append

$list = get-adgroup -properties name, managedby -filter {name -notlike "WA*" -or name -notlike "workstation*"} `
| Select name, managedby

$listing =`
$list.name + "|" + $list.managedby

$listing | Out-File $exportlist -Append
```

This is what comes out when I run it in PowerShell:

```
PS F:\> $Header = `
>> "Group ID Name" + "|" + "ManagedBy"
>>
PS F:\> write-host $Header
Group ID Name|ManagedBy
PS F:\> $list = get-adgroup -properties name, managedby -filter {name -notlike "WA*" -or name -notlike "workstation*"} `
>> | Select name, managedby
PS F:\> $listing =`
>>    $list.name + "|" + $list.managedby
PS F:\> write-host $listing
|
```

Looks like `$listing` contains nothing?

Comment: Have you tried sending `$Header` and `$listing` out to the screen just to see if they actually contain anything?

Comment: please look at my edit. The only thing that prints is my "|" line

Comment: So is the problem that *nothing* is put into the text file or that *only the header* shows up in the text file?

Comment: Looks to me like `Get-ADGroup` doesn't produce a result, or the resulting object has empty `name` and `managedby` properties. Verify that by running `Get-ADGroup -Properties name, managedby -Filter {Name -notlike "WA*" -or Name -notlike "workstation*"}` by itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After thinking some more about it: the most likely scenario is probably that you're using PowerShell v2 and `Get-ADGroup` produces more than one result. In PowerShell v2 `$list.Name` would not expand to a list of the `Name` properties of all array elements, but the (nonexistent) property `Name` of the array object, thus resulting in `$null`, which is then cast to an empty string during the string concatenation.

*Property expansion in PowerShell v2:*

```
PS C:\Temp> $PSVersionTable.PSVersion.ToString()
2.0
PS C:\Temp> $f = Get-ChildItem
PS C:\Temp> $f

    Directory: C:\Temp

Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
----                -------------     ------ ----
-a---        03.12.2014     20:38          0 a.txt
-a---        03.12.2014     20:38          0 b.txt

PS C:\Temp> $f.Name
PS C:\Temp> $f | select -Expand Name
a.txt
b.txt
```

*Property expansion in PowerShell v3:*

```
PS C:\Temp> $PSVersionTable.PSVersion.ToString()
3.0
PS C:\Temp> $f = Get-ChildItem
PS C:\Temp> $f

    Directory: C:\Temp

Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
----                -------------     ------ ----
-a---        03.12.2014     20:38          0 a.txt
-a---        03.12.2014     20:38          0 b.txt

PS C:\Temp> $f.name
a.txt
b.txt
PS C:\Temp> $f | select -expand Name
a.txt
b.txt
```

With that said, your objective seems to be to export the names and managers of AD groups to a file, separated by `|` characters. However, you're trying *way* too hard. You can easily do it just by using the [`Export-Csv`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849932.aspx) cmdlet, which allows you to specify whatever delimiter you like.

```psh
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

$exportlist = 'C:\Temp\managedby.txt'

$attr = 'Name', 'ManagedBy'
$fltr = { Name -notlike "WA*" -or Name -notlike "workstation*" }

Get-ADGroup -Properties $attr -Filter $fltr | Select $attr |
  Export-Csv $exportlist -NoType -Delimiter '|'
```

If you want the name of the manager rather than the distinguished name, use a [calculated property](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730948.aspx) for resolving it:

```psh
Get-ADGroup -Properties $attr -Filter $fltr |
  Select Name, @{n='ManagedBy';e={Get-ADObject -Identity $_.ManagedBy | select -Expand Name}} |
  Export-Csv $exportlist -NoType -Delimiter '|'
```

Comment: Thank you. The -noType -Delimiter '|' seemed to do the trick. Appreciate it!